# Python function with excessive number of variables

Tags: python

Very general question: I am attempting to write a fairly complext Python script.

```
#Part A: 100 lines of python code
#Part B: 500 lines of python code
#Part C: 100 lines of python code
```

Assume that I want "Part B" taken out of the picture for readability and debugging purposes, because I know that it is running well and I want to focus on the other parts of the code.

I would define a function like this:

```
def part_b():
    #500 lines of python code

#Part A: 100 lines of python code
part_b()
#Part C: 100 lines of python code
```

The problem with this approach in my case is that there are more than twenty variables that need to be sent to "Part C". The following looks like bad practice.

```
def part_b():
    global var1
    global var2
    global var3...
```

I am aware that I could return an object with more than twenty attibutes, but that would increase complexity and decrease readability.

In other words, is there a pythonic way of saying "execute this block of code, but move it away from the code that I am currently focusing on". This is for a Selenium automation project.

Comment: Some would argue, myself included, that 500 lines is *way* too much for a function. Even 100 is at the limit of whatever *concern* you're trying to implement. What you likely need here is a `class` where that instance can store all kinds of context used from one stage to the next. Each of these has access to `self.whatever` without having to take it as explicit arguments.

Comment: Right.  Each function has an input state and an output state.  Consider having the state be in a dictionary or a class instance.  That gives you a lot of flexibility without resorting to globals.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're looking for is modules. Move `part B` into a separate file, and then import it.

```py
import part_B

# part A here

part_B.run()

# part C here
# to access things that part B does:
do_part_C_stuff(part_B.something)
```